# Hardware Requirements Gap Analysis for Windows

Tags: windows-10, parallel-processing

I have an algorithm that needs to be repeated ('replication') a minimum of 30 times: each replication could be run in it's own core.

[The Ninja development stations feature the "Knight's Landing" (72 cores) and are outfitted with CentOS.](http://dap.xeonphi.com/)   The software I am using requires Window 10, which supports 2 phsyical sockets and 256 logical cores.

to use the station with Windows 10 on the Ninja Station, What are:

- the questions that need to be asked?
- obstacles that need to be overcome?
- is there any hardware requirement that is not met by the Ninja
  stations?